# React.js Updating state where multiple API endpoints are involved

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, axios

I'm currently trying to get a project working to test some things and I'm stuck at a point where I'm trying to update the state properly.

I have an endpoint accessed via `axios.get("/docker/containers")` which will return an array for all IDs of the containers which are currently running on my system this is done like so:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateContainers(), 3000);
};
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

At this point my state looks like this:

```js
state = {
  containers: [{id: 'id1'}, {id: 'id2'}]
}
```

The user interface then just shows a list of IDs.

I can then click on an ID on my user interface and it will set a watcher:

```js
state = {
  containers: [{id: 'id1', watcher: true}, {id: 'id2'}]
}
```

The point of the watcher is so that on the next update cycle more detailed information about a particular container is retrieved.

```js
state = {
  containers: [{id: 'id1', watcher: true, name: 'container1'}, {id: 'id2'}]
}
```

Upon clicking the container in the user interface where a `watcher` is already set then the `watcher` is dropped and the more detailed information is then no longer retrieved

```js
state = {
  containers: [{id: 'id1', watcher: false}, {id: 'id2'}]
}
```

Where I'm getting stuck is on how to get the more detailed information. My `updateContainers` method has 3 steps:

1. Read the response from the API and destruct the state into separate variables, compare the state var with the response var and remove any containers that have gone down (no `setState` is done here).
2. Add any new containers from the response to the state that have since come up (again no `setState`).

...All good thus far...

3. Loop through the filtered array of containers from steps 1 and 2 and find any containers where a `watcher` is set. Where it is set perform an API call to retrieve the more detailed info. Finally set the state.

In step 3 I use a `forEach` on the filtered array and then do an `axios.get("/docker/containers/id1")` where a `watcher` has been set otherwise simply keep the container details I already have but that's where I get stuck, *Typescript* is also giving me the error:

```
TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'IndividualContainer[]'.
```

currently I have:

```
updateContainers() {
  axios.get('/docker/containers')
    .then(response => {
       const apiRequestedContainers: string[] = response.data.containers;
       // array of only IDs
       const stateContainers: IndividualContainer[] = [
         ...this.state.containers
       ];
       // remove dead containers from state by copying still live containers
       let filteredContainers: IndividualContainer[] = [
         ...this.filterOutContainers(stateContainers, apiRequestedContainers)
       ];
       // add new containers
       filteredContainers = this.addContainerToArray(
         filteredContainers, apiRequestedContainers
       );
       return this.updateContainer(filteredContainers);
     })
     .then(finalArray => {
       const newState: CState = {'containers': finalArray};
       this.setState(newState);
     });
};

updateContainer(containers: IndividualContainer[]) {
  const returnArray: IndividualContainer[] = [];
  containers.forEach(container => {
    if (container.watcher) {
      axios.get('/docker/containers/' + container.id)
        .then(response => {
          // read currently available array of containers into an array
          const resp = response.data;
          resp['id'] = container.id;
          resp['watcher'] = true;
          returnArray.push(resp);
        });
    } else {
      returnArray.push(container);
    }
    return returnArray;
  });
};
```

Any pointers to where my logic fails would be appreciated!

Edit:

Render Method:

```
render() {
  const containers: any = [];
  const curStateOfContainers: IndividualContainer[] = [...this.state.containers];
  if (curStateOfContainers.length > 0) {
    curStateOfContainers.map(container => {
      const container_id = container.id.slice(0, 12);
      containers.push(
        <Container
                   key          = {container_id}
                   container_id = {container.id}
                   name         = {container.name}
                   clickHandler = {() => this.setWatcher(container.id)}
        />
      );
    });
  }
  return containers;
}
```

Comment: Please explain method `addContainerToArray`

Comment: In that method I add containers from my initial response object to the state. So in the case where a new container has come online for example.

Comment: please explain this method. It should return an array of IndividualContainer

Comment: Which line gives you the TS error?

Comment: So the method takes 2 arrays, the first array is the containers already in app state, the second is the containers received by the latest get request, any containers in the get request that are not in the state then get added, any containers in both arrays get preserved from the state, this is due to the requirement to keep the watcher param.

Comment: const newState: CState = {'containers': finalArray}; gives the TS error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I've commented on errors in your code:

```js
updateContainers() {
  axios.get('/docker/containers')
    .then(response => {
       ...
       return this.updateContainer(filteredContainers);
         // returns `undefined`...
     })
     .then(finalArray => { ... });
       // ...so `finalArray` is `undefined` - the reason for TS error
       // Also `undefined` is not a `Promise` so this second `then()`
       // doesn't make much sense
};

updateContainer(containers: IndividualContainer[]) {
  const returnArray: IndividualContainer[] = [];
  containers.forEach(container => {
    if (container.watcher) {
      axios.get('/docker/containers/' + container.id)
        .then(response => {
           ...
           returnArray.push(resp)
             // because `axios.get()` is asynchronous
             // this happens only some time after
             // `.then(finalArray => { ... })` is finished
        });
        // at this moment code inside `.then()` has not been executed yet
        // and `resp` has not yet been added to `returnArray`
    } else {
      returnArray.push(container)
        // but this happens while `forEach()` is running
    }
    return returnArray;
      // here you return from `forEach()` not from `updateContainer()`
      // also `forEach()` always returns `undefined`
      // so even `return containers.forEach(...)` won't work

  });
  // no return statement, that implicitly means `return undefined`
};
```

Now, why the @RocKhalil's answer, kind of, works:

```
async updateContainers() {
  const response = await axios.get('/docker/containers')
    // he favors a much clearer syntax of async/await
  ...
  const containers = await this.updateContainer(filteredContainers)
  this.setState({ containers });
};

async updateContainer(containers) {
  return containers.map(async (container) => {
    if (container.watcher) {
      const response = await axios.get('/docker/containers/' + container.id)
        // Because `axios.get()` was **awaited**,
        // you can be sure that all code after this line
        // executed when the request ended
        // while this
        //   axios.get(...).then(() => console.log(2)); console.log(1)
        // will lead to output 1 2, not 2 1
      return {
        ...response.data,
        id: container.id,
        watcher: true,
      }
    } else {
       return container;
    }
  });
  // he does not forget to return the result of `map()`
  // and `map()` in contrast with `forEach()` does have a result
  // But...
}
```

But...
`containers.map()` returns an **array**. An array of `Promises`. Not a single `Promise`. And that means that

```js
  const containers = await this.updateContainer(filteredContainers)
```

waits for nothing. And `updateContainer()` function is not actually `async`.
To fix that you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
  const containers = await Promise.all(this.updateContainer(filteredContainers))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the included reasoning!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in TypeScript so I had to change the response to JS and thought you'll re-write it in TS in case it's needed.

```
  async updateContainers() {
    const response = await axios.get('/docker/containers')
    const apiRequestedContainers = response.data.containers; // array of only IDs
    
    const stateContainers = [...this.state.containers];
    // remove dead containers from state by copying still live containers
    let filteredContainers = [...this.filterOutContainers(stateContainers, apiRequestedContainers)];
    // add new containers
    filteredContainers = this.addContainerToArray(filteredContainers, apiRequestedContainers);

    const containers = await this.updateContainer(filteredContainers)
    this.setState({ containers });
  };

  async updateContainer(containers) {
    return containers.map(async (container) => {
      if (container.watcher) {
        const response = await axios.get('/docker/containers/' + container.id)
        
        // read currently available array of containers into an array
        return {
          ...response.data,
          id: container.id,
          watcher: true,
        }
     } else {
        return container;
      }
    });
  }
```

Here's what I've updated in updateContainer:

- I'm now mapping the array instead of doing a forEach
- I'm now waiting for the container details API to return a value before checking the second container. --> this was the main issue as your code doesn't wait for the API to finish ( await / async )

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've implemented it however I'm getting an error in the render method:

Uncaught TypeError: container.id is undefined
    render Containers.tsx:138
    render Containers.tsx:137
    React 11
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:653
    React 6
    updateContainers Containers.tsx:88

A console log of container = await... shows an array of promises.

Comment: I've added my render method to the original post in case it helps

Comment: @Oceanic_Panda yes, because what you currently have is a list of Promises instead of the actual container info in the array. Can you please share the file with us so we can see the issue directly ? Viewing chunks of code with potential `line error` won't help resolving the issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are returning nothing from `updateContainer` method which will return `void` implicitly:

```
// This function return void
updateContainer(containers: IndividualContainer[]) {
  const returnArray: IndividualContainer[] = [];
  containers.forEach(container => {
    if (container.watcher) {
      axios.get("/docker/containers/" + container.id).then(response => {
        // read currently available array of containers into an array
        const resp = response.data;
        resp["id"] = container.id;
        resp["watcher"] = true;
        returnArray.push(resp);
      });
    } else {
      returnArray.push(container);
    }
    // this is inside the forEach callback function not updateContainer function
    return returnArray;
  });
}
```

Then you assign `void` to `containers` which is supposed to be of type `IndividualContainer[]` so TypeScript gives you an error then you set that in the state:

```
updateContainers() {
  axios
    .get("/docker/containers")
    .then(response => {
      const apiRequestedContainers: string[] = response.data.containers; // array of only IDs
      const stateContainers: IndividualContainer[] = [
        ...this.state.containers
      ];
      // remove dead containers from state by copying still live containers
      let filteredContainers: IndividualContainer[] = [
        ...this.filterOutContainers(stateContainers, apiRequestedContainers)
      ];
      // add new containers
      filteredContainers = this.addContainerToArray(
        filteredContainers,
        apiRequestedContainers
      );
      // this return void as well
      return this.updateContainer(filteredContainers);
    })
    // finalArray is void
    .then(finalArray => {
      // you assign void to containers which should be of type IndividualContainer[]
      const newState: CState = { containers: finalArray };
      // containers will be set to undefined in you state
      this.setState(newState);
    });
}
```

You meant to do this:

```
// I added a return type here so that TypeScript would yell at me if I return void or wrong type
updateContainer(containers: IndividualContainer[]): IndividualContainer[] {
  const returnArray: IndividualContainer[] = [];
  containers.forEach(container => {
    if (container.watcher) {
      axios.get("/docker/containers/" + container.id).then(response => {
        // read currently available array of containers into an array
        const resp = response.data;
        resp["id"] = container.id;
        resp["watcher"] = true;
        returnArray.push(resp);
      });
    } else {
      returnArray.push(container);
    }
    // removed the return from here as it's useless
  });
  // you should return the array here
  return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. I'm happy this helped. If you still have any issues I would gladly help.